# iOS App Download Page Down?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app

The download page seems to be down. I'm getting Error 500 over and over. I'm getting directed from the app (with Chrome) and going straight to the error page.

Comment: You might consider including more information, like which link you're referring to and a link to the error page. That way when a dev shows up they don't have to ask clarifying questions and then wait for you to come back. This leads to faster service for you and less back and forth for the devs. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: @jmort253 You're not supposed to share the link to the download page, per the alpha testing agreement, heh.

Comment: For what it's worth I'm unable to repro this right now, it may have been a temporary issue.

Comment: Exactly @Tim. I think this is enough info for the problem without giving away stuff I'm not supposed to share.

Comment: But it's back now, so never mind.

Comment: Gotcha @TimStone, my goal was just to make sure this wasn't some Stack App iOS tool someone put together. Just in case... Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been a temporary issue. Marking as [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).